# printf displays a different value

Tags: c

I've got a variable i that is initialized to 1, when I want to display it, it displays 6421788 instead of 1.

```
int i = 1;

    printf("WELCOME: OUR AVAILABLE TRIPS:\n");//displaying trips
    while(fgets(trip,sizeof(trip),StrdFile) != NULL)
        {
        printf("%i.",&i);//the problem
        printf("%s\n",trip);
        i++;
        }
```

This is the part of the code that must be the problem. The display need to be :

```
1.\*info*
2.\*info*
```

but what I get is

```
6421788.\*info*
6421788.\*info*
```

also, I checked the value of i in the debugger and it's correct.

Comment: `&i` is the address of (a pointer to) `i`.  The `%i` format specifier expects an `int` not an `int*`.

Comment: Those magic `&`'s are only needed for `scanf`, not `printf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing the address of `i` (kinda). Replace

```c
printf("%i.",&i);    // Address of `i`
```

with

```c
printf("%i.",i);     // Value of `i`
```

Enable and heed your compiler's warnings! With `gcc`, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`; it would have caught this error.

```
a.c:10:18: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’,
but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%i.",&i);//the problem
                 ~^   ~~
                 %ls
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually printing the number of the memory address which is reserved for your `i` variable .
Getting this address is done by adding the sign `&` before the variable name.

```
printf("%i",&i);
```

Will print the address of memory address reserved for your var `i`

```
printf("%i",i);
```

Will print the value in your var `i` .

Take a look here : https://documentation.help/C-Cpp-Reference/printf.html

Comment: To be clear: `printf("%i",&i); ` will not necessarily print _any_ address. `%i` expects an `int` on the stack, not a pointer. Everything that happens has _undefined behavior_.

Comment: In particular, if addresses are passed in different registers from numbers, you may get almost anything printed.